# mutableMap.setValue(...) function no longer exist?

Tags: kotlin, collections

In the documentation, I see we have `setValue` for a mutableMap.
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/set-value.html

```
operator fun <V> MutableMap<in String, in V>.setValue(
    thisRef: Any?,
    property: KProperty<*>,
    value: V)
```

However when try using it, it doesn't seem to exist. (I'm using Kotlin 1.3)

```
   val a = mutableMapOf(1 to 1, 2 to 3)
   a.setValue(...) // error out
```

Is it not available anymore?

Comment: The error says that `setValue` extension is provided for `MutableMap<in String, ...>`, i.e. for a map that can take `String` keys. And you're invoking it on a map with `Int` keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an extension that implements the `setValue` method required on a type for it to be used as a [proprety delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html). The official documentation covers how Maps can be used as delegates here: [Storing Properties in a Map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map).

TLDR, you get to use this kind of syntax, delegating properties into a Map instance:

```
class User(val map: Map<String, Any?>) {
    val name: String by map
    val age: Int     by map
}
```

---

If you want to simply set values of a `MutableMap`, use the [`set`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/set.html) method, also available as the `[]` operator:

```
val map = mutableMapOf(1 to 1, 2 to 3)
map.set(2, 2)
map[2] = 2
```

Or the [`put`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/put.html) method, which also returns the previous value stored by the key you modified:

```
val oldValue: Int = map.put(2, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide further context of my finding on how to use `setValue` directly, created an example below.

```
    data class Something(val boo: String? = null)

    @Test
    fun testSetValue() {
        // Showing auto delegate value of foo, which uses
        // setValue under the hood to extract 1000 for foo
        val foo: Int by mutableMapOf("foo" to 1000)
        println(foo)  // 1000

        // Demonstrating setValue ussage directly setting boo value
        val x = mutableMapOf("abc" to 1)
        x.setValue(null, Something::boo, 200)
        println(x)    // {abc=1, boo=200}

        // Similarly for `getValue`
        println(x.getValue(null, Something::boo) // 200
    }
```